# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{8ab+8ac+9bc}{(2b+c)(b+2c)}}\geq5$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $ab+ac+bc\neq0$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt{\frac{8ab+8ac+9bc}{(2b+c)(b+2c)}}+\sqrt{\frac{8ab+8bc+9ac}{(2a+c)(a+2c)}}+\sqrt{\frac{8ac+8bc+9ab}{(2a+b)(a+2b)}}\geq5$$

I tried Holder, but without success.

For example, Holder even with $(ka^2+b^2+c^2+nab+nac+mbc)^3$ does not help.

SOS or C-S seems very ugly here.

The equality occurs also for $(a,b,c)=(1,1,0)$, which adds a problems.

Comment: Looks like a tough nut. ...

Comment: @Andreas Sometimes I think that this inequality is wrong, but I don't see a counterexample.

Comment: Equality occurs also for $(a,b,c) = (0,b,b)$. Further, I can prove that the inequality holds for $(a,b,c) = (0,b,c)$. The remaining case, due to homogeneity, is then  e.g.  $(a,b,c) = (1,b,c)$. But you don't acknowledge partial proofs ....

Answer (score 2):

There is the following estimation of Nguyenhuyen_AG.
$$\sqrt{\frac{8a(b+c)+9bc}{(2b+c)(2c+b)}} \geqslant\frac{17a^2-b^2-c^2+20(ab+ac+bc)}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2+4(ab+bc+ca))}$$

Comment: Nice. Is it easy to prove the estimation?

Comment: @River Li I think, it's not so easy, but it solves the problem.

Comment: (+1) It is actually a nice form.

Comment: Local Symmetric Method..

Comment: Try $a= 1000, b= 1/100, c= 74955$, Mr. @MichaelRozenberg ?

Comment: @bamboo_jjvy271 For your values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ the right hand side is negative.

Comment: Oh my mistake..

Comment: Mr. @MichaelRozenberg, I hope to see your other solutions, agree ?

Comment: @bamboo_jjvy271  I still have no another solution....

Comment: Sos or Cauchy-Schwarz ?

Answer (score 1):

The Buffalo Way works. Due to symmetry, assume that $a\ge b\ge c$.

Let 
$$X = \frac{9}{25}\frac{8ab + 9bc + 8ca}{(2b+c)(b+2c)}, \quad
Y = \frac{9}{25}\frac{8bc + 9ca + 8ab}{(2c+a)(c+2a)}, \quad
Z = \frac{9}{25}\frac{8ca + 9ab + 8bc}{(2a+b)(a+2b)}.$$

We need to prove that $\sqrt{X} + \sqrt{Y} + \sqrt{Z} \ge 3$.

We will use the following bounds:
$$\sqrt{x} \ge f(x) = \frac{22x(5x+6)}{25x^2 + 181x+36}, \quad \forall x \ge 0$$
and
$$\sqrt{x} \ge g(x) = \frac{16x(5x+3)}{25x^2+94x+9}, \quad \forall x\ge 0$$
since
$$x - \Big(\frac{22x(5x+6)}{25x^2 + 181x+36}\Big)^2 = \frac{x(x-1)^2(25x-36)^2}{(25x^2 + 181x+36)^2}$$
and
$$x - \Big(\frac{16x(5x+3)}{25x^2+94x+9}\Big)^2 =  \frac{x(25x-9)^2(x-1)^2}{(25x^2 + 94x + 9)^2}.$$

It suffices to prove that $f(X) + f(Y) + g(Z) \ge 3$.
After clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that $F(a,b,c)\ge 0$
where $F(a,b,c)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $12$.

If $c = 0$, we have
\begin{align}
F(a,b,0) &= 64a^2b^2(a-b)^2\left(52500a^6+1729775a^5b+13521612a^4b^2\right.\\
&\quad \left. +27797474a^3b^3+13521612a^2b^4+1729775ab^5+52500b^6\right).
\end{align}
The inequality is true.

If $c > 0$, let $c = 1, \ b = 1+s, \ a = 1 + s + t$ for $s, t \ge 0$,
then $F(1+s+t, 1+s, 1)$ is a polynomial in $s, t$ with non-negative coefficients. The inequality is true.

We are done.

Comment: How did you find $f(x)$?

Comment: @tthnew According to the equality condition $(a, b, c) = (1, 1, 0)$ (correspondingly $X = 36/25$), we use the method of unknown coefficients to find $\sqrt{x} \ge \frac{ax^2 + bx + c}{x^2 + px + q}$ with equality condition $x = 36/25$ etc.

Comment: It was nice solution, +1)

Comment: @tthnew Thanks. The isolated fudging by Nguyenhuyen_AG in another answer is better.

Comment: My software output the same result as Nguyenhuyen_AG for this example!

Comment: @tthnew It is nice.

Answer (score 1):

*My second proof*.

In Michael Rozenberg's answer, Nguyenhuyen_AG's idea is the so-called isolated fudging.

I got the same form using the isolated fudging technique.

We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{8ab + 8ca + 9bc}{(2b + c)(2c + b)}} \ge \frac{17a^2 + 20(ab + bc + ca) - b^2 - c^2}{3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + 12(ab + bc + ca)}. \tag{1}$$

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $a = 0$

WLOG, assume that $b = 1$. It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{9c}{(2 + c)(2c + 1)}} \ge \frac{20c - 1 - c^2}{3(1 + c^2) + 12c}. \tag{2}$$
(2) is true.

**Case 2**: $a > 0$

WLOG, assume that $a = 1$.
Let $p = b + c, q = bc$. We have $p^2 \ge 4q$.

(1) is written as
$$\sqrt{\frac{8p + 9q}{2p^2 + q}} \ge  \frac{-p^2 + 20p + 22q + 17}{3p^2 + 12p + 6q + 3}. \tag{3}$$

We only need to prove the case that
$$-p^2 + 20p + 22q + 17 \ge 0$$
or
$$q \ge \frac{p^2 - 20p - 17}{22}. \tag{4}$$

From (3) and (4), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{8p + 9q}{2p^2 + q} \ge  \left(\frac{-p^2 + 20p + 22q + 17}{3p^2 + 12p + 6q + 3}\right)^2$$
or
\begin{align*}
 f(q)&:= -160\,{q}^{3}+ \left( -600\,{p}^{2}+704\,p-424 \right) {q}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +
 \left( 168\,{p}^{4}-784\,{p}^{3}+748\,{p}^{2}+256\,p-208 \right) q\\
 &\qquad -2
 \,{p}^{6}+152\,{p}^{5}-156\,{p}^{4}-64\,{p}^{3}-2\,{p}^{2}+72\,p\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}

We have
$$f''(q) = -1200p^2 + 1408p - 960q - 848
\le -1200p^2 + 1408p - 848 < 0.$$
Thus, $f(q)$ is concave.
Also, we have $f(\frac{p^2 - 20p - 17}{22}) \ge 0$
and $f(p^2/4) \ge 0$ (easy).
Thus, we have
$f(q) \ge 0$ for all $q\in [\frac{p^2 - 20p - 17}{22}, p^2/4]$.

We are done.

Comment: Nice again +1. Isolated fudging is powerful

Comment: @TATAbox Thanks.

Comment: could you please take a look help me? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774103/how-to-prove-sqrt-frac24a1324a13bc-sqrt-frac24b1324b13ca-sqr

Comment: @TATAbox Currently I have no idea. I upvoted yesterday. I don't know why two downvotes.

Comment: It doesn't matter but thank you anyway. Does isolated fuding technique work? I think it should be unique way to kill two equality cases.

Comment: @TATAbox I haven't tried yet.