# Equality of an Inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I encountered the following problem in my textbook-

> Let $a, b, c$ be three arbitrary real numbers. Denote $$ x = \sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}, y = \sqrt{c^2-ca+a^2}, z = \sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2} $$ Prove that $$ xy+yz+zx \ge a^2+b^2+c^2 $$

**Textbook's Solution:**
Rewrite x,y in the following forms $$ x = \sqrt{{3c^2\over 4}+\left(b-{c\over 2}\right)^2}, y = \sqrt{{3c^2\over 4}+\left(a-{c\over 2}\right)^2} $$
According to **Cauchy-Schwarz** inequality, we conclude $$ xy \ge {3c^2\over 4}+{1\over 4}\left( 2b-c\right)\left(2a-c \right) $$
which implies
$$ \sum_{cyc}xy \ge {3\over 4}\sum_{cyc}c^2 +{1\over 4}\sum_{cyc}\left( 2b-c\right)\left(2a-c \right) =  \sum_{cyc}a^2. $$
**My Approach:**
From the given values of $x$ and $y$-
$$ xy = \sqrt{\left( c^2-bc+b^2\right) \left(c^2-ca+a^2 \right)} \ge c^2+c\sqrt{ab}+ab $$
So, $$xy+yz+zx \ge \sum_{cyc}a^2+\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{bc}+\sum_{cyc}bc$$
And it rests to prove that-
$$ \sum_{cyc}a^2+\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{bc}+\sum_{cyc}bc \ge \sum_{cyc}a^2 $$
$$ \sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{bc}+\sum_{cyc}bc \ge 0 $$
Now my question is that how to prove this? Or are we done?
And also if both approachs are correct, what is the equality case?
The equality case is not given in the textbook so I ask.
Thanks!

Comment: You can obtain equality cases from where you are applying C-S (in textbook's solution).

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks, I got it a few days ago in some other post of mine. But what when the equality case needs to be noticed before attempting the solution?

Comment: In my opinion, equality cases are important to design the coefficients when we are applying C-S or Holder or using bounds, etc. For example, in my previous answer, we design the bound $\sqrt{x} \ge f(x)$ according to the equality cases $x = 0, x=1, x=\frac{36}{25}$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057006/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt-frac8ab8ac9bc2bcb2c-geq5/3446826#3446826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is wrong.

Try $a=b=c$.

Id est, you got a right inequality, but after a wrong step and the proof of your last inequality is not relevant already.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111038/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-rozenberg-equality-of-an-inequality).