# $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+4bc}{b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^2+4ac}{a^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{c^2+4ba}{b^2+a^2}}\ge 2+\sqrt{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

Prove that $\forall a,b,c\ge 0$
then   $$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+4bc}{b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^2+4ac}{a^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{c^2+4ba}{b^2+a^2}}\ge 2+\sqrt{2}$$
I have some ideas but they didn't lead to simpler inequalities. I found the equality occurs for (a,b,c) = (1,1,0)
Could you help me ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you show some of your ideas? They may help..Note that the inequality occurs in general for $a=b,c=0$

Comment: Standardized a+b+c = 2. Then Elimination (sorry because of my bad English)

Comment: Mixing Variables

Comment: Gradient is zero for $a=b=c$. The minimum is $3 \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\approx 4.74$

Comment: @Raffaele When $a=b > 0, c=0$, the value is $2 + \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore did you found some ideas ?

Comment: @FrogWeII No but i think we havfe to set some biginning inequality like nguyenhuyen_ag did here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057006/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt-frac8ab8ac9bc2bcb2c-geq5?rq=1

Comment: @RiverLi This means that *Mathematica* is wrong. Try  FindMinimum[{(Sqrt[(b^2+4 a c)/(a^2+c^2)]+Sqrt[(4 a b+c^2)/(a^2+b^2)]+Sqrt[(a^2+4 b c)/(b^2+c^2)])&&a>=0&&b>=0&&c>=0},{a,b,c}]

Comment: @Raffaele You may add a constraint $a + b + c == 1$ in the code. FindMinimum[{(Sqrt[(b^2 + 4 a c)/(a^2 + c^2)] + 
    Sqrt[(4 a b + c^2)/(a^2 + b^2)] + 
    Sqrt[(a^2 + 4 b c)/(b^2 + c^2)]), 
  a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && a + b + c == 1}, {a, b, c}]

Comment: @Raffaele However, if we add $a+b+c == 3$, does not work:  FindMinimum[{(Sqrt[(b^2 + 4 a c)/(a^2 + c^2)] + 
    Sqrt[(4 a b + c^2)/(a^2 + b^2)] + 
    Sqrt[(a^2 + 4 b c)/(b^2 + c^2)]), 
  a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && a + b + c == 3}, {a, b, c}]

Comment: @RiverLi I get your result with FindMinimum only if I set $c=0$ (or $a=0$ or $b=0$).

Comment: @Raffaele Can you copy my code?  I used your code but it does not work. So I change your code a little bit.

Comment: @RiverLi with your code I get $$\{4.74342,\{a\to 0.333333,b\to 0.333333,c\to 0.333333\}\}$$

Comment: @Raffaele I get $${3.41422, {a -> 0.5, b -> 0.5, c -> 2.07714*10^-7}}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120226/discussion-between-raffaele-and-river-li).

Comment: Wolfram pro works perfect (but numerically)   $≈3.41421$  minimize | function | sqrt((a^2 + 4 b c)/(b^2 + c^2)) + sqrt((b^2 + 4 a c)/(a^2 + c^2)) + sqrt((c^2 + 4 b a)/(b^2 + a^2))
domain | a>=0 ∧ b>=0 ∧ c>=0

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, wolfram alpha also works but shows "4 local minima (no global minima found)": minimize(sqrt((a^2 + 4 b c)/(b^2 + c^2)) + sqrt((b^2 + 4 a c)/(a^2 + c^2)) + sqrt((c^2 + 4 b a)/(b^2 + a^2))) subject to a>=0,b>=0,c>=0

Comment: @RiverLi see the super solution by arquady in aops https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h260824_abcgt0

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thanks. It is nice to eliminate the root sign.